# ошибка в opencart в чем может быть дело?

Tags: php, opencart

PHP Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/a/set/public_html/system/startup.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php53/share/pear:/usr/share/pear') in /home/a/set/public_html/index.php on line 21

Comment: он же говорит в чем проблема.

Comment: а если для особо одаренных по-русски расшифровать?

Answer (score 0):

не может открыть файл /home/a/set/public_html/system/startup.php , проверьте права доступа на папку , попробуйте поставить 755

Comment: спасибо, помогло